# Why not all showing up in vs code django/python intellisense

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

Hi I am new to Python/django and am using VS Code. Now I got python IntelliSense and pylance extension installed and most things are showing up on IntelliSense but some aren't.

How can I get it to work for everything?

I would very much appreciate some insight since it's driving me nuts...

request.POST from an imported lib not showing up
[image: POST not showing in intellisence]

selected_meetup.participants not showing up nor is selected_meetup.participants.add
[image]

```
from urllib import request
from django.forms import SlugField
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Meetup
from .forms import RegistrationForm
# from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    meetups = Meetup.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'meetups/index.html', {
        'meetups': meetups
    })


def meetup_details(request, meetup_slug):
try:
    selected_meetup = Meetup.objects.get(slug=meetup_slug)
    if request == 'GET':
        registration_form = RegistrationForm()
    else:
        registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.)
        if registration_form.is_valid():
            participant = registration_form.save()
            selected_meetup.participants.add(participant)
            
    return render(request, 'meetups/meetup-detail.html', {
        'meetup_found': True,
        'meetup': selected_meetup,
        'form': registration_form
    })
except Exception as exc:
    return render(request, 'meetups/meetup-detail.html', {'meetup_found': False
                                                          })
```

---

Update:

That's great guys,  I now understand the type problem it's obvious now (only had so many extensions issues especially django/html) I got confused...

Now I added types to Meetup and Participant but selected_meetup.participants.  still refused to show me its method ADD.

I assume the problem is the lib is written without types. Is there a way to solve that? because quite valuable to me to be able to see what's possible write away...

have you got solutions to that?

[image]

Comment: You arent using any typings so it will struggle to figure out what type `request` is, especially since you compare it to a string 4 lines above

Answer (score 1):

I would re-install the extensions, then make sure it is referencing the right version of python. If that doesn't work I would recommend to just type it out in full and look past the error.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare what type of object request is in the programming process. Maybe you can declare request = request () in the code.The second is the same. vscode can't recognize the type of the selected_meetup you wrote.
You can hover over these two objects and find that the vscode prompt the type can be any.

Comment: Ahh doh now it's clear I was able to fix that my adding type to my code. but I still not getting tons of stuff from imported lib (see update) how do you handle that?

Comment: You can try this extension : "Visual Studio IntelliCode", which is Microsoft's official IntelliCode.Maybe it can work